# Debugging with semaphores in Xcode - Grand Central Dispatch - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4, grand-central-dispatch

Say have a few blocks of code in my project with this pattern:

```
 dispatch_semaphore_wait(mySemaphore);
 // Arbitrary code here that I could get stuck on and not signal    
 dispatch_semaphore_signal(mySemaphore);
```

And let's say I pause in my debugger to find that I'm stuck on:

```
 dispatch_semaphore_wait(mySemaphore);
```

How can I easily see where the semaphore was last consumed? As in, where can I see dispatch_semaphore_wait(mySemaphore); was called and got through to the next line of code? The trivial way would be to use NSLog's, but is there a fancier/faster way to do this in the debugger with Xcode 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print `debugDescription` of the semaphore object in the debugger (e.g. via `po`), which will give you the current and original value (i.e. value at creation) of the semaphore.

As long as current value < 0, `dispatch_semaphore_wait` will wait for somebody else to `dispatch_semaphore_signal` to increment the value.

There is currently no automatic built-in way to trace calls to `dispatch_semaphore_signal`/`dispatch_semaphore_wait` over time, but that is a useful feature request to file at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

One way to trace this yourself would be by creating symbolic breakpoints on those functions in Xcode, adding a 'Debugger Command' breakpoint action that executes `bt` and setting the flag to "Automatically continue after evaluating" the breakpoint.

Another option would be to use DTrace pid probes to trace those functions with an action that calls `ustack()`.